# Popover image not appearing

Tags: popover

First time here, forgive me if I'm new, but I can follow ideas.

I will give you a link to my site, as seeing the problem, you may go "ahhhhh" gotta cha! (i hope!)

I have a site that the image popover stopped working. as to which code changed, im not sure.

It is a shopify shop using .liquid with an owl carousel and lightbox within the pages, and perhaps when i used a "Live theme Editor"
code was modified.

Here is the link to an example of a page. all the product pages and  have the same problem. I can only open in a new tab, etc. to se the pic.

https://www.japandizness.net/collections/frontpage/products/new-japan-secret-honey-disney-2015-snow-white-dress-version-4

Thanks greatly for help and time on things great than i understand, but i will learn something and pass it on!

Jeff :D

Comment: A small advice: look at questions with a good score and try to rephrase your question accordingly. Go straight to it, with pasted code and a description of the issues you got.

Comment: I could see what you are saying is the way to do it, but i really dont know where the code would be, other than pasting pages and pages, i figure if i show the problem and state what tools are involved with the code, perhaps someone familiar with css, js, .liquid in shopify pages, would have a clue. so all i could do was send a link to the effect when you click images. then maybe i could get feedback on where or what to check, and i could research that more....Jeff :)

Comment: Then maybe, it's a bit too early to ask a question... I recommend you to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking especially the sections about "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" and "How do I ask a good question?".

Comment: well, im dealing with a complete website that is quite interactive in its parts, code not written by me. I have already spent 10 hours+ looking thru code for a clue and inspecting with google chome inspector.

Comment: i came here for a little help, instead of chase my tail in relation to getting a decent answer. i can only show you what is happening           https://www.japandizness.net/collections/frontpage/products/new-japan-secret-honey-disney-2015-snow-white-dress-version-4                      and someone here is smart enough and decent enough to hint more clearly. I offer help when i can regardless  of the level of understanding of the person i help. i take time to help them figure out what they cant get. So here i am asking for help on something beyond my level.

Comment: I'm sorry you take it as such. I was just trying to help you find the expert you are looking for... Good luck.

Comment: Aurelien, Im sorry. maybe I was a bit harsh.Im Frustrated with the code problem, not your fault. I looked again and perhaps there is a problem in this section of code. firefox works, but google chrome gives me only a large black 30% transparent that fills the sceen with no image.

Comment: perhaps there is a problem in this section of code.===> magnetic popup css.. too long to paste.